# Identify this component

Tags: components, identification, receiver

What would this big stainless plate be? Do they go bad? 
This is a GPS by the way, and some buzzing noise coming [image]from it. When I hold with my finger it quiets down.

Comment: It's a cover/shield for LNA circuitry. The noise is probably the hum coming from mains earth/ground.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič LNA would that be low-noise amplifier? Is that removable?

Comment: There are a bunch of IC, transistors, other components ....under that cover. Of course, what is mounted it can be also removed, but you'd need special tools.

Comment: Metal noise shield. Removing it will reduce operation quality or make it inoperable.

Answer (score 1):

Would that be a shield for the gps chip? With a grounding issue given the noise.